# Error: TensorFlow Module Not Found on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: python, tensorflow, github, raspberry-pi, tensorflow2.0

I've been working on a project and need to utilize a GitHub repository in Raspberry Pi OS (using Raspberry Pi 5). I've installed all the necessary libraries, including the specified version of TensorFlow as recommended by the repository owner. However, I'm encountering the same error indicating that the TensorFlow module cannot be found on running main.py of the repository. (I am using VS code)

Github repository: https://github.com/maddinkunze/handcode.git

The error i am getting:

The following unhandled exception occured: No module named 'tensorflow'

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File

"/home/pi/handcode/src/main.py ", line 440, in threadConvert import handwriting

File

"/home/pi/handcode/src/lib/hand writing/init_.py", line 1, in

<module>

from. import gcode

File

"/home/pi/handcode/src/lib/hand writing/gcode.py", line 3, in

<module>

from.rnn import rnn

File

"/home/pi/handcode/src/lib/hand writing/rnn.py", line 5, in <module>

import tensorflow as tf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

(<class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'tensorflow'"), <traceback object at 0x7fff9495a240>)
```

[image: The error mssg i got as specified above]

Plz help to tackle this situation.